# Accessing the array EDI points to by index

Tags: arrays, assembly, cpu-registers

I need to convert an integer value to a null-terminated string containing the integer's hexadecimal equivalent. This is the first program I have written in Assembly and I am wondering why I cannot access the value that edi points by index (an array of 8 bytes), like so:

```
mov startNum, 23
lea esi, startNum
lea edi, bNumStr
mov bx, 16

mov ecx, 7

mov ax, [esi]
WhileNotZero:
        div bx                  
        mov [edi][ecx], dl
        sub ecx, 1
        cmp ecx, 0
ja WhileNotZero
```

If I am completely misunderstanding something here, please let me know. Any advice to push me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What the name of the assembler you are using?  For MASM, you can't write [edi][ecx]; you have to write [edi+ecx].

Comment: I'm now using the stack to push dx on and then pop dx off in reverse order and add 30h in a different loop. For some reason, it lets me do [edi][ecx] that way.

Comment: Which assembler are  you using?  You can't get good help, if you won't answer questions from your would-be helpers.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is MASM.

Comment: Really?  Well, hmm, I might be wrong then.  I use MASM a lot, but have never written [edi][ecx].  Guess I assumed it wasn't legal.  Forget I said anything ... :-{

Comment: Let's start again.  You show us some code. You complain "it" doesn't work.  What is your specific evidence?  Are you using a debugger? Are you getting a complaint from the assembler?  *What* specific device is not letting you "access the value"?

Comment: Are you initializing `edx` anywhere?  `div` leaves the remainder there, so dividing `dx:ax` by `bx` is unlikely to be useful when `dx` has the remainder from the previous iteration, and `ax` has the quotient.  Also note that `sub ecx, 1` already sets flags, so you can branch on that instead of a separate `cmp`.  `dec ecx / jnz` should match the behavoiur of your current loop for all inputs (including unsigned valued greater than the largest possible signed integer).  `dec ecx / jg` works if you want to check that ecx didn't become negative if it started at zero.

Comment: See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for many good links.  And also, write `[edi+ecx]` like a normal person so people can read your code.  It looked broken to me and Ira, and we've both seen a lot of assembly.

Comment: @PeterCordes:  Its good to be old, wrong, and in good company :-}

Comment: I am terribly sorry for being so late to respond; I grew sick. To answer @PeterCordes, yes I am making sure edx is empty after each division. After I push the necessary remainders onto the stack, I have a second loop that pops them back off into edx and does this: `mov [edi + ecx*8], edx`. That, however, is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set ECX=7 your aim is to retrieve 8 hexadecimal digits and thus you have to divide the value in the dword in **EAX** by 16. Prior to this division you need to zero the EDX register.
Since you want a null-terminated string, start by writing the null.

```
    mov  ebx, 16             ;Divider
    mov  ecx, 8              ;Number of digits
    mov  eax, [esi]          ;Dividend
    mov  [edi][ecx], ch      ;Null-termination, here CH is zero
WhileNotZero:
    dec  ecx
    xor  edx, edx            ;Divide EDX:EAX by EBX
    div  ebx                 ;Quotient in EAX, remainder in EDX (<16)
    ...
    mov  [edi][ecx], dl
    cmp  ecx, 0
    jne  WhileNotZero
```

At the **...** you could insert the code to convert into actual characters.